# Understanding reference counting--windows installer

Tags: windows-installer, reference-counting

I'm trying to understand/explain why the following is happening:

1) A.msi creates a directory \path\to\foo

2) B.msi finds \path\to\foo using the registry and adds a few more files to that location

3) if B.msi is uninstalled, the additional files it adds are removed

4) if a newer version of A.msi is installed (major upgrade) before B.msi is uninstalled, subsequent uninstall of B.msi will leave the files it added to \path\to\foo.  The msiexec /x logging looks like this:

```
(SERVER)     MSI (s) (60:08) [14:09:33:018]: Disallowing uninstallation of component:  
{BIFF} since another client exists

(SERVER)     MSI (s) (60:08) [14:09:33:019]: Disallowing uninstallation of component: 
{BAM} since another client exists

(SERVER)     MSI (s) (60:08) [14:09:33:019]: Disallowing uninstallation of component: 
{HARVEY} since another client exists

(SERVER)     MSI (s) (60:08) [14:09:33:019]: Disallowing uninstallation of component: 
{ETC} since another client exists
```

So, obviously, reference counting, right?  But not in a way that I understand.  I would have thought that since each file is individually wrapped with a component and the component guids are unique that reference counting between the two MSIs would remain similarly separate/unique.

Is it the case that last installer wins when it comes to ownership of a directory and that ownership of the directory necessarily interferes with reference counting/removal of the file wrapped by the components being counted?  Does anyone have a link/documentation they can share with me on this topic?

Comment: I usually see this message in the packages from our clients only when they have the same components GUIDs. I assume you have not copied the project file used to build A.msi and re-used to build B.msi? (as this could lead to duplicated componentd GUIDs)

Comment: Correct.  Guids are unique between the components of A & B.  The only thing that is shared is the directory which B sets as a property, reading it from a registry entry that A writes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate concepts of "sharing".

1. shared components, this happens if two components have the same guid.
2. shared DLLs, this happens if either the component has the [sharedDllRefCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute set OR the file already existed.

mind that in both cases not the folder is shared, but the file (or whatever resource you place in the component)

if 1 and 2 are mixed, sometimes file are not removed on uninstall, then you have to manually remove the file or [correct the sharedDLL counter manually](http://blogs.flexerasoftware.com/installtalk/2010/11/cleaning-up-your-shared-dlls-registry-references-for-msis.html)

regarding the official documentation you asked for i couldn't find much except for this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: There's another place where files can be referenced which prevents the installer from removing them: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\... - see http://www.daviddeley.com/solutions/msiexec/index.htm